# Different CSS on homepage

Tags: css

I have this code in my stylesheet:

```
#social-icons {
    width:100%;
}
#social-icons li {
    float:right;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type:none; 
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I would like `#social-icons li` to `float:left` on all pages, except the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

In your theme's `header.php` file, before `</head>` tag, just put this code :

```
<?php
if(!is_homepage())
{
?>
    <style type="text/css">
    #social-icons li {float:left}
    </style>
<?php
}
?>
```

If you don't want to touch your theme, you can use [wp_head action hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

**After   Bruno Toffolo's comment**

If you don't like inline css, you can put homepage-specific css rules to another css file like homepage.css and then enqueue this css file with is_homepage() conditional tag.

```
<?php
if(!is_homepage())
{
    wp_enqueue_style(...);
}
?>
```

Comment: I would have +1'd your post, but inline CSS is just so ugly. :(

Comment: @BrunoToffolo you can put homepage-specific css rules to another css file like **homepage.css** and then enqueue this css file with `is_homepage()` conditional tag.

Answer (score 1):

Most WordPress themes give a CSS hook for the home page, and a number of other factors, by adding different classes to the `body` tag. Try comparing the `body` tag on your home page, and on another page.

On a site I'm working on, here is the tag for the home page:

```
<body class="home page page-id-33 page-template-default">
```

And here it is for an internal page:

```
<body class="page page-id-285 page-parent page-template page-template-page-market page-template-page-market-php">
```

The classes appended to `<body>` allow me to write different CSS in this case based on whether the page is:

- the home page,
- a page (as opposed to a post),
- a page with children (descendants in the page hierarchy),
- a page with the default template, or
- a page with a specific page template.

To target the home page, in your case, you'd write:

```
#social-icons li {
  float: left;
}

.home #social-icons li {
  float: right;
}
```

This should give you `float: left` on all pages, except home, where it will `float: right`.

If you don't see differences in the `body` tag between the home page and other pages, then your current theme doesn't have this feature baked in. You'll have to edit any files that include the `body` tag. Most themes follow the standard practice of including this just once, in *header.php*.

Wherever you find the body tag, replace `<body>` with

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> >
```

If you like you can include a string of text within the function, like this:

```
<body <?php body_class('sammich'); ?> >
```

This would have the effect of adding 'sammich' to the classes in the body tag.

**Note: If you do this to your theme, then update your theme, your coding changes will be lost. Consider doing a quick [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).**

Learn more @ http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Comment: I would add that if this isn't present in the theme, then add `<?php body_class(''); ?>` to the `<body>` element in the header or appropriate template file. Also note that you can add class(es) by passing a string or an array through this function.

Comment: Very good idea. I've updated my answer to include this—thanks!

Comment: Looks good. You're missing the closing `>` on the `<body>` in your explanation of body_class(). I tried suggesting an edit but it won't let me add only 2 characters.

Comment: Thanks. I probably would miss those while coding, too. But there my test page would instantly show me the problem :)